# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Вот бьёт такую ошибку, сижу уже с 30 минут и не могу увидеть свою ошибку(
А это в консоли браузера

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
at main (<anonymous>:18:63)
at <anonymous>:21:3
at HTMLScriptElement.eval
```

Это сам код:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name AlloY Script
// @namespace LolzteaM
// @AuTHoR AlloY
// @include https://lolzteam.net/*
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

name = 'AlloY';


var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js");
script.addEventListener('load', function() {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "window.jQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + main.toString() + ")();";
document.body.appendChild(script);
}, false);
document.body.appendChild(script);


function main() {
var AlloY = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementsByClassName('blockLinksList')[0].appendChild(AlloY);

$('.username').each(function(i) {
if ($(this).children().eq(0).text() == name) {
console.log(1);
$(this).children().eq(0).attr('class', 'style228');
var d = $(this).closest('.messageUserBlock').children('div').eq(1);
}
});

var z=0;
while (z<20)
{
var SummDok1 = document.getElementsByClassName('team_banner45')[z],
name1 = '<em class="userBanner Sanya330 wrapped" itemprop="title"><span class="before"></span><strong>S T A R</strong><span class="after"></span></em>';
SummDok1.innerHTML = name1;
z++;
}
}
```

Comment: что вам выдает console.log(SummDok1) внутри while?

Comment: очевидно элементов с классом team_banner45 меньше чем 20

Answer (score 0):

```
//var SummDok1 = document.getElementsByClassName('team_banner45')[z],
```

Попробуй поменять на =>

```
//var SummDok1 = document.getElementsByClassName('team_banner45'),

//SummDok1 = SummDok1[z],
```

Comment: как это поможет?